# Adding incremental id value to features with certain attribute value

Tags: qgis, if-statement, virtual-field

I am using QGIS 3.12. I have a layer of trees and a virtual field 'tree number' that counts all trees that I add to the layer (`$id`). I want to set that if a height of a tree is more than 3 (in field 'height') it will not be counted in the 'tree number' field. Can it be done?

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `if("height" > 3,NULL,$id)` as expression for your virtual field.

Comment: I think your solution is not full, cause as soon as a value out range occurs the id-chain will be broken. Also, I will probably write your expression it as `if("height">3, $id, NULL)`.

Comment: @Taras yes, you are almost right. Guess I misunderstood the question a little. [Your answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/373387/107424) is the one to go then, except to my logic, you transposed case_true and case_false.

Answer (score 3):

Despite a suggestion from @MrXsquared, I think this task has to be tackled a slightly different way.

To achieve a continuous id-chain, try the following expression in the Field Calculator

```py
if("height">3, array_find(array_agg($id, filter:="height">3), $id), NULL)
```

Resulting in

[image: result]

If the `"id"`s have to start with 1, then use the following expression

```py
if("height">3, array_find(array_agg($id, filter:="height">3), $id) + 1, NULL)
```

Comment: That looks greate. I thank you very very much.

Comment: please accept one of the answers as a valid one